# AngularJS - TypeError: Cannot read property 'go' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, types

I want to change my state to "login" on a button click . So , I added a button and in `ng-click`, I called up the function `registerForm` (which u can see in the below code). but when I press the button I get the following error in the browser console.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'go' of undefined 
>       at m.$scope.registerForm (controllers.js:27) 
>       at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14605), :4:227) 
>       at b (angular.js:15694) 
>       at e (angular.js:25622)
>       at m.$eval (angular.js:17444)
>       at m.$apply (angular.js:17544)
>       at HTMLFormElement. (angular.js:25627)
>       at Sf (angular.js:3488)
>       at HTMLFormElement.d (angular.js:3476)

```
app.controller('registerController', ['$scope',function ($scope,$state) {
    $scope.mismatch=true;

    $scope.$watch('retypepassword', function()
    {
        if($scope.retypepassword != null)
        {
            if($scope.password === $scope.retypepassword)
            {
                $scope.mismatch=true;
                $scope.loginForm.$setValidity("valid", true);
            }
            else
            {
                $scope.mismatch=false;
                $scope.loginForm.$setValidity("valid", false);
            }
        }
    }, true);

    $scope.registerForm=function()
    {
        $state.go('login', {});   
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Cannot read property 'go' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748030/typeerror-cannot-read-property-go-of-undefined) and a multitude of same questions found by searching SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inject $state properly

```
app.controller('registerController', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope,$state) {
```

Answer (score 2):

seems like missed to inject $state, update as follows would help resolve this issue.

```
       app.controller('registerController', ['$scope','$state',function ($scope,$state)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject $state too

```
app.controller('registerController', ['$scope','$state',function ($scope,$state) {
```